# Linux does not work

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.04 by update-manager. After that ubuntu does not work anymore. It gives just dark screen and nothing more. So I can't use anything in ubuntu . can anyone help me? I can't log in and I don't have usb or cd because I used update-manager to upgrade

Comment: There is no official supported way to upgrade 14.04 to 15.04. You did it at your own risk. I suggest a fresh install of 14.04 or 15.04.

Comment: what I have to do exactly, please. I have no experience with linux!

Comment: Exactly. Re-install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the recovery menu during boot:

Press the F8 key during boot right after the PC bios have loaded (try it a couple of time if you can't get into the recovery menu).

Hereafter will  you be presented with a boot menu where you can go to recovery mode.

When booted up in recovery menu there is an option to start a root shell.

In the root shell you can start to diagnostic problems.

First look in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/syslog. to find problems.

```
$ less /var/log/syslog
```

Also look in /var/log/dmesg and /var/log/sddm.log

```
$ less /var/log/dmesg
```

To quit *less* type *q* key on the keyboard.

If you are using a newer NVidia graphic card (GTX970 or GTX980) you will have to install the [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) driver for the graphic card.

The can be done from recovery root shell as well.

Comment: Maby he'll find some clues, but is seems to complex for OP to fix those problems, hence his commentary ("what I have to do exactly, please. I have no experience with linux!")